# How to resolve the ZIMBRA mail server error?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1WPR.jpg)

While I installing the package of the Zimbra mail server, the attached error is coming, and cannot rectify it. Pls, give me the correct solution.

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.